# How do you grow a mushroom around a ring?

Tags: fungus

There's a lass that I'm very intrigued by, and am planning to get her a purity ring. She knows I love mushroom hunting, and cultivating, so I want to grow a mushroom around a purity ring before the next time we have dinner together. How can I ensure the ring grows inside the mushroom (like a jewelry box)?

Comment: My advice is to use the mushrooms for dinner and keep the ring in a real jewelry box...

Comment: i grow a lot of my own mushrooms in my gated yard, so it will be safe.

Comment: You might be able to place a ring inside a mushroom then give it a few days to heal itself. It may kill the mushroom but then again it may heal itself and grow around it. Either way, please don't give her the mushroom with the ring in it and tell her to take a bite. She could choke or break a tooth.

Comment: I'll give it to her when making the dish.

Comment: It might be easier to grow the mushroom through the ring, like a finger. Of course, it may also be really creepy, unless the ring were high up the "stem" and just under the cap; that way she wouldn't see it unless she turned the mushroom upside down.